# Minimise the median of the distances from a string

Tags: algorithm

## The problem

Lets consider you have a list of strings `r, s, t, ...`. How could you determine the string `u` such as `M = Med(d(r, u), d(s, u), d(t, u), ...)` is minimised?

`d` is a function which returns the distance between two strings (lets say it is the Levenshtein distance).

I cannot find out a clever way to determine `u`. One could brute force the thing computing `M` for every word of length `max(#r, #s, #t, ...)` but it would be amazingly slow.

## Idea

Maybe can one try to modify each string such as it becomes closer to at least one other. Let me give an example with the words:

- `Python`
- `Java`
- `Racket`

We could start with `Java` and store `Pava` because it is closer to `Python` than `Java` is but not with `Oava`. Finally we compute `M` for every single stored word. However I am not convinced it would work.

Comment: Not sure that you can do better than brute force (O(n²) complexity)

Comment: O(n^2) is still impressive if n is thew length of the longest string. Could you explain me how to achieve that? My brute-force was trivially in O(26^n). I must miss something

Comment: That's not an easy problem and you are right, to be more precise I was speaking of time complexity [more context](http://www.ok.sc.e.titech.ac.jp/res/PCS/courses/comp644/).

Comment: I will read your link, thank you

Comment: you are welcome, that's an interesting problem, I tried to google it but found nothing more than brute force. good luck

Comment: An approximate solution: find the clique with ceil(n/2) members that has the smallest diameter, then find the centroid of that clique. In your example, we have `diameter(Python,Java) = 6`, `diameter(Python,Racket) = 6`, `diameter(Java,Racket) = 5`. So the clique of size 2 with the smallest diameter is `(Java,Racket)`. The centroid of that clique is `Jack` since the distance from `Jack` to `Java` is 2, and the distance from `Jack` to `Racket` is 3.

Comment: @user3386109 your answer is damn smart. I just wonder how to determine the centroid. If you manage to explain that, please make it an answer.

Comment: @user3386109 how would we define adjacency for the purpose of enumerating the cliques?

Comment: Just suppose the graph is fully connected with weighted edges.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Blincer's comment is correct. All nodes are adjacent to all other nodes, and the edge weight is the Levenshtein distance (or another distance metric if Levenshtein isn't being used).

Comment: @Blincer Finding the centroid of any two strings is fairly simple when using Levenshtein distance. Levenshtein distance is based on a series of single character edits. If you perform half of those edits, then the resulting string is the centroid. Using that logic, the centroid of (Java,Racket) is Raca since that's two edits away from Java. So you could compute all the pairwise centroids and see how well each one works as the centroid for the clique.

Comment: What about taking the centroid of centroid of pairs until one word is left?

Comment: Have you considered [medoids](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medoid) rather than or as an intermediate step to median?

Comment: The problem with medoids is that you select a word in the original corpus, you cannot reach the minimum.